Late 80s/early 90s movie about a satanic cult, hero dies in the end
Unfortunately, I don't recall much about this movie.
It is set in "modern day" (late 80s/early 90s).  It involves a satanic cult that goes around killing people.  If I recall, the main hero is a guy (a reporter, perhaps) who stumbles on to the cult because a woman's boyfriend is killed (or something like that).
The biggest thing I remember about the movie is that in the end, the hero is captured by the cult and taken off to be sacrificed.  You see some police show up at the scene, but instead of arresting people or saving the guy, they change into the cult's robes and the hero ends up getting killed.  The woman lives, if I recall (and maybe has a voice-over at the end).  The cult is not stopped.
I saw it only once, many, MANY moons ago.  Any help with this would be appreciated.
This was an American film based in California. Greater LA area most likely.

Sounds like Spellbinder from 1988 starring Kelly Preston.

The film that you're looking for is Spellbinder from 1988 starring Kelly Preston and Tim Daly.
The main protagonist is actually an attorney played by Tim Daly.  His best friend, played by Rick Rossovich is a cult member whose true identity is revealed at the end of the film.
The protagonist is taken to be sacrificed at the end of the film.  The police officers that were called to help reveal themselves to be cult members as well.

In the end, it’s all a clever plot to lure men in positions of power,
  who have lost all their family, to a beach where the ritual is
  performed. The victim must go there of their own will. Daly finds
  everyone in his life, including his best friend, and even the police
  are in on this grand plot. He has his heart cut out and Miranda is
  saved from being sacrificed herself.


Many thanks, SteelersFan!  The name sounds familiar!
